# rsync files from one remote server to another

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I am looking for the command to transfer files from one remote server to another. I can ssh into the remote servers and am curious as to what flags I might need to use. Also do I need to cd into the files directory on the old respository(on the old server) to run the command?

Here is what I think my options are:

```
rsync -arv . server@ip_of_server:/path_to_files_dir server@ip_of_server:/path_to_files_dir
```

or

```
rsync -azvhe ssh --exclude 'styles/*' --exclude 'js/*' --exclude 'css/*' files/ username@ip.address.of.server:/var/www/path-to-files
```

But I don't want to exclude css or js...

Comment: You are going to run into trouble. `rsync` is a transfer between the calling host and dest only. Any daisy chain will require a script invoking `rsync` between the two other hosts. (either by cron or triggered by an `ssh` command), that will require public/private key access between the other 2. (don't get me wrong, you can ssh into `host 1` and then `rsync host1->host3`, but you can't do `rsync host1 -> host3` from `host2` alone.

Comment: As long as you can `ssh` between all 3 hosts, just `ssh` into oldserver and then `rsync -uav --exclude..... newserver:/path` no need to specify the `-e ssh` transport (that is the default). I think that is closer to what you were asking? No?

Comment: There aren't three hosts. I just want to copy files from one remote server to another. I was just explaining that I can ssh into the server's so an ssh flag might not be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. All you need, as explained, is the `rsync -uav stuff` form or you may like the abbreviated for `rsync -uai stuff` form. Youf `--exclude` syntax is fine. `rsync` is by far the most useful and efficient file transfer routine around. It is just as capable at transferring local files as it is in remote transfers.